# Kotlin native readLine() truncate stdin data

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

I have a file with very long lines around 10^6 zeros and ones if I use kotlin 1.4.20 native `readLine()` the std input `cat pub07.in | ./alg.kexe` is randomly truncated and it doesn't respect any line breaks. Any ideas?

The input files can be seen in  public [data sets](https://cw.felk.cvut.cz/brute/data/ae/release/2020z_b4m33pal/pal2020/evaluation/input.php?task=bordernetworks)

Comment: Probably a bug. Try on the JVM to confirm.

Comment: JVM working as expacted. Same code just changed BufferedReader to readLine().